# Get last field using awk

Tags: awk

I am new to awk and want to have awk in shell script to select ami name in my automation pipeline

`{"us-west_ami" :"ami-123" }`

I want to select "ami-123" and pass it new job.

I tried to use print $NF but it is not selecting the last value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print $NF` indeed does select the last field but first you need to define what are the record and field separators (`RS` and `FS`). In this case it would be easiest to use Gnu awk and define the `FPAT`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="\"[^\"]+\""}{print $NF}' file
"ami-123"
```

See [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) for more details on `FPAT`.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

if it is json format, use the right tool, e.g. `jq`:

```
kent$  jq '."us-west_ami"' <<<'{"us-west_ami" :"ami-123" }'
"ami-123"
```

Comment: ^1 though I suspect the OP really just wants `jq '.[]' <<<'{"us-west_ami" :"ami-123" }'` since she said she wants to get the "last field".

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is not right tool to parse `json`, but still for given input this will work

```
$ grep -oP '"us-west_ami"(\s+)?:\K[^,}]*' <<< '{"us-west_ami" :"ami-123" }'
"ami-123"
```

To save in variable

```
$ myvar=$(grep -oP '"us-west_ami"(\s+)?:\K[^,}]*' <<<'{"us-west_ami" :"ami-123" }')

$ echo "$myvar"
"ami-123"
```